# Apex 5 Add new row at the and of interactive grid

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5.1

I'm a new user of oracle apex 5. I'm using interactive grid but i have a problem, by default apex 5 add the new row after the selected row, but i want add the new row after the latest row.
How can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know, but - why do you care about position where row is **inserted**? It is - after all - stored into a RDBMS table, and in those tables there's no "order" of rows; think of them like apples in a basket. Which one is first, which one is last? You can't tell until you **sort** them, and that's done with the `ORDER BY` clause.

Which, in your case, means: the next fetch (or refresh) will sort them properly anyway.

Comment: Hi, I use this ineteractive grid to make revisions or estimates, and once written and printed I don't want the lines to be mixed up on the next print, possible that there isn't a system to insert the new line at the end of the grid?